# Enums shared static look-up method

Tags: java, enums

I have the following Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum{
    A(10, "First"), //
    B(20, "Second"), //
    C(35, "Other options");

    private Integer code;
    private String description;

    private MyEnum(Integer code, String description) {
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public static MyEnum getValueOf(Integer code) {
        for (MyEnum e : MyEnum.values()) {
            if (e.getCode().equals(code)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No enum const " + MyEnum.class.getName() + " for code \'" + code
                + "\'");
    }
}
```

Which works fine. The `getValueOf`-method exists because when communicating with an external partner, we only get the code (they chose) to map to. I need the description because I need to show a meaningfull phrase in the GUI.

But I now have a number of similar enum classes. All having their own code & description, and they need the same lookup functionality. 
I wanted the `getValueOf`-method to be generic so I don't need to support 30+ different enums for basically the same method.

To solve this I wanted to make an abstract class to define this method and implement some of the common logic but this is impossible because I can't extend `Enum`.

Then I tried to make a Utility class with the following method:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T getValueOf(Enum<T> type, Integer code) {...}
```

But generics with Enums are confusing and I don't understand how to get this working.

Basically what I want to know is: What is a good approach to define a common utility to an enum?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to pass the actual enum class object as a parameter to your method. Then you can get the enum values using `Class.getEnumConstants()`.

In order to be able to access `getCode()` on the instances, you should define it in an interface and make all your enum types implement that interface:

```
interface Encodable {
    Integer getCode();
}

public static <T extends Enum<T> & Encodable> T getValueOf(Class<T> enumClass, Integer code) {
    for (T e : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (e.getCode().equals(code)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No enum const " + enumClass.getName() + " for code \'" + code
            + "\'");
}

...

public enum MyEnum implements Encodable {
    ...
}

MyEnum e = getValueOf(MyEnum.class, 10);
```

Comment: FYI, the above could throw a NPE if getCode returns null. I would put a check in the `if` conditional for null.

Comment: @JohnB, indeed. I copied the code from the OP and didn't bother to improve it. If anything, instead of a null check I would change the type of `code` to `int` to nip the problem in the bud.

Comment: I actually took this and incorporated in my own utility project. Made `Encodable` generic so the method became `public static <U, T extends Enum<T> & Encodable<U>> T getValueOf(Class<T> enumClass, U code)` Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @JohnB, not at all - I don't consider it my intellectual property as I also learned it from others. Glad to hear you found it useful!

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit tricky because the `values()` method is static. You would actually need reflection, but there is a nice way to hide this using standard library functionality.

First, define an interface with the methods common to all of your enum types:

```
public interface Common {
    Integer getCode();
    String getDescription();
}
```

Then, make all your enums implement this interface:

```
public enum MyEnum implements Common {...}
```

The static method you want to have then looks like:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & Common> T getValueOf( Class<T> type, Integer code ) {
    final EnumSet<T> values = EnumSet.allOf( type );
    for(T e : values) {
        if(e.getCode().equals( code )) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "No enum const " + type.getName() + " for code \'" + code + "\'" );
}
```

Comment: Beaten by 15 seconds, oh well. The only thing I'd change is to use `getEnumConstants()` instead of creating an EnumSet - that seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @Voo Yes, pretty much the same answer, but didn't  think that many people would know it right away. ^^ Well, EnumSets are quite efficient, the overhead should be low, but I didn't know this method to be honest. I do not see a disadvantage of using `getEnumConstants()`, but I will leave my answer as it is, because there is another answer using it yet.

Comment: Your comment puzzles me. Do you see an answer added by @Voo? Or what other answer you are referring to?

Comment: @PéterTörök I assumed that Voo was referring to your answer, because you are using the `getEnumConstants()` method and there is no other answer here. So my comment is related to your answer (which I think Voo's comment is about as well).

Comment: Except that my answer predates yours by more than 10 minutes :-)

Comment: @PéterTörök You are right, I did not realize that ^^ Maybe he wanted to add an answer himself then.

Comment: Yeah that was the basic idea. When I wrote the comment Péter hadn't yet updated his version, so there was no code using getEnumConstants around, but I figured it wasn't worth writing up a version that was identical except for one single method.